# Backbone each undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

Why is the item variable undefined in this Backbone example?

```
var Action = Backbone.Model.extend({
defaults: {
    "selected": false,
    "name": "First Action",
    "targetDate": "10-04-2014"
}
});

var Actions = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Action
});

var actionCollection = new Actions( [new Action(), new Action(), new Action(), new Action()]);

_.each(actionCollection, function(item) {
    alert(item);
});
```

jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/netroworx/KLYL9/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change it to:

```
actionCollection.each(function(item) {
        alert(item);
});
```

And it works fine.

This because actionCollection is not an array, so _.each(collection) does not work but collection.each does because that function is build into Backbone collection.

That being said, this also works:

```
_.each(actionCollection.toJSON(), function(item) {
        alert(item);
});
```

Because now the collection is an actual array.

Answer (score 0):

`_.each` accepts an array as first argument, but you passed a `Collection`.

Just use the `Collection.each` method:

```
actionCollection.each(function(item){
  //do stuff with item
});
```